# Join two list using multivalued lookup field with spquery

Tags: caml, spquery

I have joined two lists with the lookup that allow single value using spquery.join. can any one help me to do for multivalue lookup

Answer (score 1):

Finally i come to point that it is not possible to join two list using lookupmulti type..
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/018a47b5-b9e7-46cd-b008-d806bf8ef240/